# ¿porque aparecen las tildes y las ñ alteradas en mi páginas de heroku?

Tags: html, git, heroku

Esta es mi página de heroku
https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/
Aqui hay un artículo de ejemplo

https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/paginas%20principales/google%20ncr.html

En esta página aparecen todas las tildes alteradas, yo utilizo sublime text para editar los archivos, como veran en el localhost antes de subirlo a heroku aparecen bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿qué causa esto? ¿qué debo de hacer? ¿quitar todas las tildes y las ñ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es por que te faltó este meta(utf-8), agrega estas líneas de código dentro de tu etiqueta < head>< /head>, te servirán igual.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title></title>
```

Comment: si añado eso, ya las tildes me van a aparecer normales?

Comment: Así es, a darle un git push heroku master

Comment: es entre head y title verdad?, si me funciona te voy a elegir como mejor respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias se me arreglo todo, y me podrian explicar que quiere decir estas metas <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

Comment: @AlexandraLoor Una trata la compatibilidad con internet explorer y la otra te refleja el tamaño de la pantalla al cargar (initial-scale=1 significa que aparezca como debería naturalmente sin ningún zoom)

Comment: gracias, he visto que también ponen el idioma como meta tag, me podrias informar para que sirve?

Answer (score 1):

Agrego a lo que dice el colega **@JorgeLuis** que debes tomar en cuenta cuando utilices tu editor de texto que al **guardar el archivo** lo guardes en **codificación "UTF-8"** porque muchos por defecto se guardan automáticamente con **codificación "ANSI"** la cual no es la indicada para lo que pides. Un Saludo

Comment: tengo que simplemente agregar el codigo, o tengo que también darle a guardar como a todas las páginas?